# Unable to install a CGIProxy script on Ubuntu server

Tags: perl, ubuntu, proxy, cgi

I'm trying to install CGIProxy on Ubuntu.

http://www.jmarshall.com/tools/cgiproxy/install.html#install

Basically it's a single "nph-proxy.cgi" file which I placed in my /var/www folder.
It's supposed to display a simple GUI form where a user can enter a URL and access the website behind a firewall.

I used this command from the instructions:

`./nph-proxy.cgi install-modules`

Nothing seems to happen and when I navigate in my browser to the ip address with the "nph-proxy.cgi", all I see are a whole page of code whereas instead I should see a GUI form.

I'm still new to linux and modules and any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you set executable permission on the script?  If not, do `chmod 755 nph-proxy.cgi`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer to this problem, basically you have to not only have Perl installed on ubuntu but also enable it to run cgi scripts. Take a look at this article, it explains to how to get apache to run cgi scripts. Just remember, you have to explicitly tell apache to allow cgi scripts to run, it's not automatic.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-apache2-webserver-with-phpcgi-and-perl-support-in-ubuntu-server.html